# More than and less than logic

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to build code for a VBA user form.

I am trying to state that if a postal area "BT" and a weight less than or equal to 30 then the cost will be £15.15, there would then be an additional cost for each unit over 30 of 0.65.

If the postal code is anything other than "BT" with a weight less than or equal to 35 then the cost will be £4.73, for each additional unit over 35 it will be 0.25

The following is not calculating correctly.

```vb
Private Sub Weighttb_Change()
    If PostCodecb = "BT" Then
        UKMtb = 15.51 + (Weighttb - 30) * 0.65
    ElseIf Weighttb <= 35 And PostCodecb <> "BT" Then
        UKMtb = 4.73 + (Weighttb - 35) * 0.25
    Else
        UKMtb = "4.73"
    End If
End Sub
```

---

The code is for a userform. `PostCodecb`, `UKMtb` and `Weighttb` are my named text boxes, cb being combo box.

Comment: What are `PostCodecb`, `UKMtb` and `Weighttb`? Some global variables? Named ranges? Controls?

Comment: Hi, the code is for a userform these are my named text boxes.

Comment: cb being combo box.

Comment: `And PostCodecb <> "BT"` is not necessary, how did you declare `UKMtb`? Probably, numeric, so `UKMtb = "4.73"` should be `UKMtb = 4.73`. if the cost should be "less than or equal to 30", why using `ElseIf Weighttb <= 35`?  Where do you intent to use it?

Comment: Hi, because the postal location of BT has a different costing requirement compared to all the other postcodes.

Comment: If you answer my question (if so, you should tag me...), why saying "less than or equal to 30"? How to be  helped if you requires something in words and write something else in code. The, what "not calculating correctly" should mean? You should know what you need, from this point of view. If not, at least take two values and show us what the code returns **against what you want**. And in such a way we can deduce what you really wont, not being able to explain it...

Comment: @FaneDuru if the postcode BT is selected from a dropdown list along with a weight that is 30kg or less then I should be shown within UKMtb a returned value of £15.51. If the weight is more than 30kg then an additional cost of 0.65p per kilo should be added.

If a postal code that is not BT is chosen with a weight less than or equal to 35kg then the price is £4.73. For each additional unit after 35kg the charge is 0.25p per kg.

Hope this is clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just need to separate the calculation for each postal code.

Also, the second part of the calculation, `+ (Weighttb - 30) * 0.65` will introduce errors if a value below the base is passed, e.g. 20 instead of 30, since it will calculate `-10 * 0.65`.

See an example below with some tests. Not sure what the *units* are, so I assume they are whole numbers (integer).

```
Private Function CalculateCost(ByVal postCode As String, ByVal weight As Integer) As Double

    Select Case postCode
        Case "BT":
            CalculateCost = 15.51 + IIf(weight > 30, (weight - 30) * 0.65, 0)
        
        Case Else:
            CalculateCost = 4.73 + IIf(weight > 35, (weight - 35) * 0.25, 0)
    End Select
End Function
```

---

A few tests to verify the outcome:

```
Sub T()

    'BT
    Debug.Print "Expected: " & 15.51, "Got: " & CalculateCost("BT", 30)
    Debug.Print "Expected: " & 15.51 + 5 * 0.65, "Got: " & CalculateCost("BT", 35)
    Debug.Print "Expected: " & 15.51, "Got: " & CalculateCost("BT", 20) 'below base
    
    'Other
    Debug.Print "Expected: " & 4.73, "Got: " & CalculateCost("NBT", 35)
    Debug.Print "Expected: " & 4.73 + 5 * 0.25, "Got: " & CalculateCost("NBT", 40)
    Debug.Print "Expected: " & 4.73, "Got: " & CalculateCost("NBT", 25) 'below base

End Sub
```

---

The outcome:

```
'Expected: 15.51    Got: 15.51
'Expected: 18.76    Got: 18.76
'Expected: 15.51    Got: 15.51
'Expected: 4.73     Got: 4.73
'Expected: 5.98     Got: 5.98
'Expected: 4.73     Got: 4.73
```

---

To call it in your sub:

```
Private Sub Weighttb_Change()

    UKMtb = CalculateCost(PostCodecb, Weighttb)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,

@Kostas K. thank you so much for the help.

I have tried the above code but i need the result to show in my UKMtb (text box)

I tried to amend but no success


```Private Sub Weighttb_Change()

Private Function CalculateCost(ByVal PostCodecb As String, ByVal Weighttb As Integer) As Double


    Select Case PostCodecb
        Case "BT":
            CalculateCost = 15.51 + IIf(Weighttb > 30, (Weighttb - 30) * 0.65, 0)
        
        Case Else:
            CalculateCost = 4.73 + IIf(Weighttb > 35, (Weighttb - 35) * 0.25, 0)
    End Select
End Function
End Sub```

Comment: See edit above. You just need to pass the form values to the function and show the return value.